# python set own currency with locale

Tags: python, locale, currency

I would like to set my own currency (preferred behind it instead first)

```
def total_price(self):
    items = SellItem.objects.filter(selllist=self)
    total = 0
    for item in items:
        total += item.amount * item.price

    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
    total = locale.currency(total, grouping=True)
    return total
```

now i would like to use the grouping but instead of the $ up front, i would like ISK at the back.
Not quite sure how to accomplish this

Comment: Here's your answer; http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.localeconv `p_sign_posn` and `n_sign_posn`. You can easily configure the currency format with these parameters. Use `int_curr_symbol` and `currency_symbol` for the symbol ISK.

Comment: Sorry still bit new to Python and not sure how i use it, since it tells me localeconv() doesnt take any arguments. I tried locale.localeconv(p_sign_posn=4, currency_symbol="ISK")

Comment: I misled you a bit by accident, sorry. That function just returns the settings. You need to set the http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.LC_MONETARY settings and then use http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.currency function.

Comment: Sorry have to say i still dont quite get it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try the example below. first print statement will give your current locale value as string (Ex : en_IN for india) and second will provide you a tuple which has both locale value and iso code ( Ex : ('en_IN', 'ISO8859-1'))

```
import locale
print locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print locale.getlocale()
```

Comment: Hmm, i go read again a bit more. Thanks for the help, but not yet working for me